# How is a variable in Python represented in memory?

Tags: python, variable-assignment, cpython

So let's take `a = 5` as an example.

On many sites, the diagrammatic representation in memory is shown as the following:

```
              ________
              |       |
       a ---->|   5   |
              |_______|
```

But shouldn't it be shown as the following?

```
        a
     _______        ________
     |      |       |       |
     |   ---|------>|   5   |
     |______|       |_______|
```

I mean that isn't it exactly the same as pointers in C if we are talking about the CPython implementation?

Answer (score -1):

Python employs a different approach. Instead of storing values in the memory space reserved by the variable, Python has the variable refer to the value. Similar to pointers in C, variables in Python refer to values (or objects) stored somewhere in memory.